# Select and move cells based on value change in rows

Tags: if-statement

I have a spreadsheet with a few thousand lines, which i need to reformat to allow for missing data. What I am using is columns A to M, where Columns A, C, E, H, K and M contain numbering data and the rest are unimportant numbers. What I need my script to do is check row by row if the value of a=c=e=h=k=m. If they do match then move onto the next row (where the numbers increment by one (row 1 should have 1's in a,c,e,h,k,m, row 2 should have 2's etc)). If a number changes I need to move the rest of the row where the change occurred down so the numbers in a,c,e,h,k and m realign.

```
Sub ()
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim curRow As Integer
    Dim sel As Range
    Dim elt As Range
    Dim mybool As Boolean
    Dim Mini As Integer
    Dim col As Integer

    'Worksheet name and cells range
    With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:M")

        curRow = 1
        lastRow = .Rows.Count
        col = .Column
        mybool = True
        Mini = 0

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Do While curRow < lastRow

            'Worksheet name...
            Set sel = Intersect(.Rows(curRow), Union(Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(col), _
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(col + 2), Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(col + 4), _
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(col + 7), Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(col + 10), _
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(col + 12)))

                 For Each elt In sel
                    If elt.Value > Mini Then
                        If elt.Column <= col + 4 Then
                            elt.Offset(0, 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                        ElseIf elt.Column >= col + 10 Then
                            elt.Offset(0, -1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                        ElseIf elt.Column = col + 7 Then
                            elt.Offset(0, 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                            elt.Offset(0, -1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                        End If
                        elt.Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                    End If
                Next
                lastRow = lastRow + 1
            End If

            curRow = curRow + 1
            mybool = True
            Mini = 0

        Loop

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Your variables are mixed up? By `c(a,x)`, do you want Cells(rowa, colx)? You can't have `if v1 = v2 = v3`.  Instead: `If v1 = v2 and v1 = v3`. Where are you setting x (the row or column?)?

Comment: `Columns("a, c, e, h, k, m")` should be `Columns("a", "c", "e", "h", "k", "m")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you confirm how the ranges in columns b, d, f, g, i, j, and l should move? should they follow the pattern of the ranges directly on their right or left?

I have put together some code that answers your requirements  - as far as I understand - for columns a,c,e,h,k,m, but I am confused what to do with the rest of them.

Edit: The below looks to work

Just to elaborate on the logic of the code so that you can better appreciate whether this actually covers for all requirements here:

- it iterates over every row of a dynamic range - made up of your original range plus any new rows that may be added to it as part of the iteration process by moving down some of the cells from the original range
- for each iteration, the routine looks at the value in each cell of the A, C, E, H, K and M columns in the current row; for each one of these cells, if both the value is superior to the minimum value among the group and the cell is not empty, then the cell moves down - alongside any cell that pairs with that cell from columns B, D, F, G, I, J, and L

Here is how columns are paired: A-B, C-D, E-F, G-H-I, J-K, L-M

This code assumes no colum headers in the range

Your just need to fill in the name of YOUR_WORKSHEET_NAME and YOUR_RANGE_ADDRESS in a couple sections of the code identified by comments before running:

```
Sub reshape_range()
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim curRow As Integer
    Dim sel As Range
    Dim elt As Range
    Dim mybool As Boolean
    Dim Mini As Integer
    Dim col As Integer

    'ENTER YOUR_WORKSHEET_NAME AND YOUR_RANGE_ADDRESS HERE
    With Worksheets("YOUR_WORKSHEET_NAME").Range("YOUR_RANGE_ADDRESS")

        curRow = 1
        lastRow = .Rows.Count
        col = .Column
        mybool = True
        Mini = 0

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Do While curRow < lastRow

            'ENTER YOUR_WORSHEET_NAME HERE
            Set sel = Intersect(.Rows(curRow), Union(Worksheets("YOUR_WORKSHEET_NAME").Columns(col), _
            Worksheets("YOUR_WORKSHEET_NAME").Columns(col + 2), Worksheets("YOUR_WORKSHEET_NAME").Columns(col + 4), _
            Worksheets("YOUR_WORKSHEET_NAME").Columns(col + 7), Worksheets("YOUR_WORKSHEET_NAME").Columns(col + 10), _
            Worksheets("YOUR_WORKSHEET_NAME").Columns(col + 12)))

            For Each elt In sel
                If elt.Value <> "" Then
                    If Mini = 0 Then
                        Mini = elt.Value
                    Else
                        If elt.Value <> Mini Then
                            mybool = False
                            If elt.Value < Mini Then Mini = elt.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            If Not mybool Then
                For Each elt In sel
                    If elt.Value > Mini Then
                        If elt.Column <= col + 4 Then
                            elt.Offset(0, 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                        ElseIf elt.Column >= col + 10 Then
                            elt.Offset(0, -1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                        ElseIf elt.Column = col + 7 Then
                            elt.Offset(0, 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                            elt.Offset(0, -1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                        End If
                        elt.Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                    End If
                Next
                lastRow = lastRow + 1
            End If

            curRow = curRow + 1
            mybool = True
            Mini = 0

        Loop

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. In my spreadsheet i need the cells to the right of a,c,e,h,k,m to stick with them as they correspond to eachother. So the contents of a&b c&d e&f, g,h&i, j&k, l&m  must move together but it is a change in a,c,e,h,k,m which are the triggers for inserting the new cells. In the example above on line 5 you can see that there is a 4 and then all 5's, i need to leave the 4 in column a and its partner column b on a row by itself, then move the rest of the row down.

Answer (score 0):

We have been pointing out the more obvious syntax errors without properly looking at your code.

You want this for every row of the worksheet.  I would normally suggest:

```
Dim x as Long

For x = RowStart to rowMax
  :   :   :
Next
```

However, you are inserting new rows so you cannot use a `For` Loop.  I will return to this issue later and for the moment assume you can use a `For` Loop.

You do not need `For Each c In Columns("a", "c", "e", "h", "k", "m")` because you are not looping through these columns.

What you need is:

```
For x = RowStart to rowMax
  If Cells(x, "a") = Cells(x, "c") And Cells(x, "c") = Cells(x, "e") And _
     Cells(x, "e") = Cells(x, "h") And Cells(x, "h") = Cells(x, "k") And _
     Cells(x, "k") = Cells(x, "m") Then
  Else
  :   :   :
  End If
Next
```

However, this is not correct because you are selectively moving values down.

In your example, column A is not equal to Column C so you move Columns C to M down.  I assume if Column A was equal to Column C but Column C was not equal to Column E, you would move Columns E to M down.  If columns A, C and E are equal, Columns H to M move down.  And so on.

Is this description closer to your requirement?  Can you have Columns A, E, H, K and M equal with Column C being different?

I am happy to suggest some code that I believe will meet your requirement once I am convinced I have a full understanding of your requirement.